# How to find the asymptotic expansion of error function at infinity?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, asymptotics, special-functions

I'm trying to understand the asymptotic behavior of (analytic) error function $\mathrm{erf}(z)$ when $z\to\infty$, here the error function is defined on the whole complex plane:
$$\mathrm{erf}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\Gamma}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}dt$$
where $\Gamma$ is the line segment connecting $0$ and $z$. This function has an essential singularity at $z=\infty$.

I'm trying to find the asymptotic expansion of $\mathrm{erf}(z)$ at $z=\infty$, this can be done by taking the expansion of $\mathrm{erf}(1/z)$ at $z=0$. I know from Wolfram Alpha that the result is
$$\mathrm{erf}\Big(\frac{1}{z}\Big)=e^{-1/z^2}\left(-\frac{z}{\sqrt{\pi}}+O\left(z^2\right)\right)+(-1)^{\lfloor\mathrm{Arg}(z)/\pi+1/2\rfloor}$$

But I don't know how compute this. Any references or hints will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Write $\int\limits_0^z dt = \int\limits_0^\infty dt - \int\limits_z^\infty dt$, then integrate the second term by parts

Comment: Write $$
\operatorname{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\int_0^z {{\rm e}^{ - t^2 } {\rm d}t}  = 1 - \frac{2}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\int_z^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - t^2 } {\rm d}t}  = 1 - \frac{z}{{\sqrt \pi  }}{\rm e}^{ - z^2 } \int_0^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - z^2 s} (1 + s)^{ - 1/2} {\rm d}s} 
$$ and apply Watson's lemma.